# what is the ` char in JS and how to run it in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, multiline, backticks

I use the `` ` `` char for multi lines in JS (especially with `document.write`) which is very useful.

ex:

```
<script>
document.write(`hello 
    world
    line2
`);
</script>
```

However I don't really understand what it stands for (and worse) it does not work at all in IE9-IE10-IE11.

Is there a clean alternative to write `document.write` multi line ?
(I loved that method to avoid using extra chars like `\` or having to write `document.write` for each line until I realized it fails on Internet Explorer)

Comment: I think you might have to do it the old way in IE unfortunately. Check out this MDN article https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Comment: It's called a backtick. Google "backtick Javascript".